# 2sxc Employee app List sort in visual query by modified date

Tags: 2sxc

For my pourpose I need to sort Employee app list items by last modified date.
I see that in the object there is a Modified  that is a date field (I assume it is a 2sxc internal field).
Using the Value sort datasource setting Modified as attribute I get an empty object.
It does work using my custom fields as sorting attribute.
What I'm missing please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the value-filter didn't include modified till very, very recently, like v08.05.04 or similar. Since then I believe it was added - see https://github.com/2sic/eav-server/blob/master/ToSic.Eav.DataSources/ValueFilter.cs#L146-L167

So I believe if you upgrade it should work.

Comment: I would need to use the Modified date in the ValueSort, but after upgrade I can't even see the Modified date in the object result, like before.
But now I can't see it anymore https://snag.gy/WKPzBJ.jpg.
I thought that it was a "core" field that i could use to sort my data by modified date.

Comment: Btw trying to define this sorting filter https://snag.gy/OtHZpq.jpg I just get the default strem empty.

Comment: Sometimes I'm able to see Modified in the stream, sometimes not... I don't understand it, but I'm stille unable to sort by Modified... 
https://snag.gy/0XDNiz.jpg

Comment: You are right - I just checked the code for the SORT data-filter and it doesn't have the internal field Modified on the list. I think it would be easy to add 0.5h or so + some tests etc. I recommend you create an issue in github and for now just do it in code using LINQ or in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you, that's right, I will use LINQ for now and opening an issue on github.